# Is the ideal $\langle X^2-Y , Y^2 +4 \rangle$ prime in $\mathbb{Q}[X,Y]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ideals

> Is the ideal $\langle X^2-Y , Y^2 +4 \rangle$ prime in $\mathbb{Q}[X,Y]$?

I've tried to find elements in this ideal which are products of polynomials not in the ideal, but so far nothing seems to factor nicely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quotient ring
$$\frac{\mathbb{Q}[X,Y]}{\langle X^2-Y , Y^2 +4 \rangle}$$
is isomorphic to
$$\frac{\mathbb{Q}[X]}{\langle X^4 +4 \rangle}.$$
The polynomial $X^4+4=(X^2-2X+2)(X^2+2X+2)$ is reducible.
The quotient ring is therefore a product of two fields, and so your
ideal is not prime.